# Is there any way to do like below?

Tags: excel, vba, automation

how to open multiple urls from excel sheet and take the screenshots of those opened url site pages and save those screenshots which stores in the same sheet of excel with different image names in one folder using excel macro, vba

I tried using for loop to open the websites, the code is taking the screenshots but the images are saving with overwrite, getting the last image saved in the destination folder, but i need different images with different names, meaning that the for loop should work for saving the images with different names.

let me explain you further:

i have 3 URLs in my current excel sheet and using below script, i can open the 3 URLs and capturing the 3 screenshots in sequence. but i'm getting only the final screenshot in my folder but not the first and second. The first pic is getting overwritten by second pic and the second pic is overwritten by the third pic and finally remains the third pic in the folder.

VBA Script/Macro i used:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
  bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12
Private Const PREFIX As String = "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Snapshots\"

' Export Shape, as a picture, to a file
Function ExportPicture(shp As Shape, sFile As String, sFilter As String) As Boolean
     On Error GoTo errExit
     Dim CH As ChartObject
     Set CH = shp.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, shp.Width, shp.Height)
     CH.Activate
     CH.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse ' to allow transparency if PNG
     CH.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
     CH.Chart.Paste
     CH.Chart.Export sFile, sFilter
     ExportPicture = True
errExit:
     If Not CH Is Nothing Then CH.Delete
End Function


Sub OpenMultipleSites()

    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    HL.Follow
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))


' to take screenshot
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0 'Key Down
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 'Key Up


    
' wait for screenshot ready
    Dim t As Single: t = Timer + 1.1: Do While Timer < t: DoEvents: Loop

    
    
' paste screenshot to sheet and export or save the pic as jpg pic.
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        Dim shp As Shape
        Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        ExportPicture shp, PREFIX & ".jpg", "jpg"
        shp.Delete

    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, there is a way to do it. But until you give us a [mcve] of what you're doing, we cannot advise how to fix your code.

Comment: edited the question for more clarity, could you please check and do the needful.